# Is $0.a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}\cdots a_{n}\cdots$ with $a_{n}\equiv \lfloor n\sin{n}\rfloor\pmod {10}$ a rational number?

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion, rationality-testing

Let $a_{i}\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}, (i=1,2,\cdots,n,\cdots)$, and such that
$$a_{n}\equiv \lfloor n\sin{n}\rfloor\pmod {10}$$

I conjecture :
$\qquad   0.a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}\cdots a_{n}\cdots$ is rational number?

Comment: Do the decimals repeat?

Comment: @SimpleArt   Yes.It's it

Comment: Why do you conjecture that this is rational? I would think it is not, as rationality is equivalent to this sequence being eventually periodic, but $\sin(n)$ is not periodic (as a function of integers) and $n\sin(n)$ looks even less periodic.